# What's the CallingUid when AppX calls ServiceY which then calls ServiceZ?

Tags: android, process, uid, android-binder

From Android API documentation: `Binder.getCallingUid()` returns the Linux uid assigned to the process that sent you the current transaction that is being processed. When AppX calls ServiceY and ServiceY calls `getCallingUid()`, it will get UID for X.

My question is: when AppX calls ServiceY, and ServiceY in turn calls ServiceZ, what's the calling UID observed by Z?

Does it make a difference if Y and Z are in the same process?

Answer (score 0):

If App X calls Service Y, and Service Y calls Service Z, when Service Z calls `getCallingUid()`, it will get back the UID for Service Y.  This will be the case even if Y and Z are in the same process as each call is considered a separate Binder transaction.

Comment: What I found out is, if Y and Z are in the same process, getCallingUid() returns X. The Binder calls between Y and Z becomes plain local function calls.